# SQL Change a user's password with MUST CHANGE argument

Tags: sql, passwords

I am using Visual Studio 2015 (vb).  When we add a user to our app we generate a sql script and then execute that script manually using sql management new query.
The new user is added with a randomly generated password but with MUST CHANGE.
This works ok but it requires a manual intervention in the app process.

Should the user forget their chosen password, we generate a new random password and a SQL script to update the DB. Thus:

```
Dim SQLscript As String = String.Format("ALTER LOGIN [{0}] WITH PASSWORD = N'{1}' MUST_CHANGE,  CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON ;",
                                        msSelectedUserName, 
                                        tab2txtNewPassword.Text)


My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(SQLscript)


MessageBox.Show("New Password SQL script is copied to the Clipboard", "Open MSSM & run this script",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

This all very well but the manual intervention is less than desirable.  I am aware that there are dynamic SQL script generators but I am frightened to death of executing over the web where malicious intervention could cause havoc.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: How is your application connecting to the database?  How are you handling the rest of the database interactions?  How about a web end point that you send via a known email address that allows a user to reset their passwords?

Comment: Yes I agree that this is confusing.  We have more than one application.  Our users they know nothing of this.  We have a management application that controls what our users can see and what they can do within the application they actually use.  To make our life easier our management app allows us to control new users, existing users, etc.  So the user will never see what goes on only that they do not have issues running what they see.  This issue relates to the management of users.  Since we manage the users, our management app can be interventional.  I would rather it not be so.

Comment: Another point to note is that our databases are hosted (AWS) and communications are over the web using stored procedures.  Adding or updating a user logon credentials are real issues and the crux of this question.

Comment: Did not answer William Jones Question completely.  The user can change their password, once they are logged on.  This is simple using SQL inbuilt procedure             SqlConnection.ChangePassword(msConnectionString, msUserNewPassword).